# NUnit DataSource from a different class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I am trying to make a test project using N Unit. I have everything working and now but i was wondering if it is possible to split the test cases into a completely separate class or would the only feasible way would be to push the data to a file or a partial class? basically I would like the data in a separate file instead of having all the data and the tests in one file. Or maybe that more of the standard and create different classes for each rule test.

```
[Test, TestCaseSource("TenantsRules")]
    public void CheckDNQTenantsRules(DNQTenantData testData)
    {
        CoreServicesBroker.DNQCoreServiceBroker broker = new CoreServicesBroker.DNQCoreServiceBroker();
        string actualDNQReason = string.Empty;

        int actualReturnCode = broker.CheckDNQTenants(testData.FormCode, testData.StateCode, testData.EffectiveDate, testData.NumberOfTenants, ref actualDNQReason);

        Assert.AreEqual(testData.ExpectedDNQReturnCode, actualReturnCode);
        Assert.AreEqual(testData.ExpectedDNQReason, actualDNQReason);
    }

public static IEnumerable<DNQTenantData> TenantsRules()
    {
        yield return new DNQTenantData() { FormCode = 9, StateCode = "OH", EffectiveDate = DateTime.Now, NumberOfTenants = 7, ExpectedDNQReturnCode = 1, ExpectedDNQReason = "Number of Tenants exceeded." };
        yield return new DNQTenantData() { FormCode = 9, StateCode = "OH", EffectiveDate = DateTime.Now, NumberOfTenants = 5, ExpectedDNQReturnCode = 0, ExpectedDNQReason = "" };
    }
```

Comment: How about a baseclass? But its Hard to tell what you are actually trying to do since you didn't post actual code to give an expression what exactly you are trying to extract.

Comment: not sure if N unit could accomplish that but I can try. Would you put the data in the base and derive the tests off of it?

Comment: yeah, but like i said, post some code and tell us what you'd like to extract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe NUnits [TestCaseData](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseData) will solve your problem:

```
[TestFixture]
public class YourTest
{
    [Test, TestCaseSource(typeof(YourTestCaseProvider), nameof(YourTestCaseProvider.TenantsRules)]
    public void CheckDNQTenantsRules(DNQTenantData testData)
    {
        CoreServicesBroker.DNQCoreServiceBroker broker = new CoreServicesBroker.DNQCoreServiceBroker();
        string actualDNQReason = string.Empty;

        int actualReturnCode = broker.CheckDNQTenants(testData.FormCode, testData.StateCode, testData.EffectiveDate, testData.NumberOfTenants, ref actualDNQReason);

        Assert.AreEqual(testData.ExpectedDNQReturnCode, actualReturnCode);
        Assert.AreEqual(testData.ExpectedDNQReason, actualDNQReason);
    }
}

public class YourTestCaseProvider
{
    public static IEnumerable TenantsRules()
    {
        yield return new TestCaseData(new DNQTenantData() { FormCode = 9, StateCode = "OH", EffectiveDate = DateTime.Now, NumberOfTenants = 7, ExpectedDNQReturnCode = 1, ExpectedDNQReason = "Number of Tenants exceeded." })
        yield return new TestCaseData(new DNQTenantData() { FormCode = 9, StateCode = "OH", EffectiveDate = DateTime.Now, NumberOfTenants = 5, ExpectedDNQReturnCode = 0, ExpectedDNQReason = "" });
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help! ;)

Comment: Putting your data into a separate class is exactly how TestCaseDataSource is intended to be used. The ability to use the test class is maintained because many people got used to it, but I don't think it's the best way to structure things.